# Is there anything for the hootsuite extension not read the xml from my web?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, hootsuite

I would like to know if:
Is there anything for the hootsuite extension not read the xml from my web?
such as html class: class = "nothootsuite"

This is because I have a link xml, rss is not, and when I click it opens my window extension "hootsuite"

I hope to have solution without having to uninstall the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the settings and turn off the "use hootsuite to open RSS" option.